# Como modificar esta query para obter o resultado desejado no Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, query, active-record, viewmodel

Tenho uma SQL que me retorna o seguinte:

> 1: Hacker E Automóveis
>
> **OU**
>
> 2: Alimentos

e preciso que ela me retorne:

> 1: Hacker
>
> **E**
>
> 2: Automóveis OU Alimentos

O código que eu tenho até agora é:

```
    if(!$final['termo'] == null) {

        $this->db->like('bl_title', $final['termo']);
    }

    if(!$final['categorias'] == null) {

        $c = 0;

        foreach($final['categorias'] as $cats){

            $c++;

            if($c == 1){

                $this->db->where('bc_urllink', $cats);

            } else {

                $this->db->or_where('bc_urllink', $cats);  
            }    
        }
    }
```

Falta um parênteses na condição `where/or_where` do **bc_urllink** que eu não sei como colocar.

Em SQL puro, ela é assim:

```
    $result = $this->db->query("
                                SELECT * FROM blogs AS bl 
                                INNER JOIN blog_categoria AS blc 
                                ON bl.bc_id = blc.id 
                                WHERE bl.bl_title 
                                LIKE '%Hackers%'
                                AND (blc.bc_urllink = 'automoveis'
                                OR blc.bc_urllink = 'alimentacao')
                                ");
```

Agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que usar o [query-grouping](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update_batch#query-grouping), comandos:

> `$this->db->group_start();`

e aqui você coloca as condições e finaliza:

> `$this->db->group_end();`

---

aplicando no seu código, dentro do `if`, foi feito algumas modificações:

```
if(!$final['termo'] == null) 
{
    $this->db->like('bl_title', $final['termo']);
}

if(!$final['categorias'] == null && count($final['categorias']) > 0) 
{

    $c = 0;        
    $this->db->group_start(); //inicia o grupo
    foreach($final['categorias'] as $cats)
    {
        $c++;
        if($c == 1)
        {
            $this->db->where('bc_urllink', $cats);

        } 
        else 
        {
            $this->db->or_where('bc_urllink', $cats);  
        }    
    }
    $this->db->group_end(); // termina o grupo
}
```

**Referencia:**

[CodeIgniter - query-grouping](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update_batch#query-grouping)

Comment: Que TOP esse agrupar hein @Virgilio, obrigado cara.

Comment: Legal mesmo @MarcosVinicius !!! show de bola temos todas as opções ... vlw